# .NET MAUI app + MediaPicker is crashing with Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I use the built-in `MediaPicker` to access user's photos. The app works fine until I tap the icon to access the photos. It then crashes with the following error message:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException   Message=Drawable
> com.mycompany.myapp:mipmap/appicon with resource ID #0x7f0d0000

I did replace the app icon recently and I also noticed that the app is not using it when I run the app on an actual device. I simply put a new `svg` file in the `Resources/AppIcon` folder with the same name as the original i.e. `appicon.svg`.

In the properties for this file, I set it as `MAUIICON`.

This is what's in the project file:

```
<!-- App Icon -->
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
```

In case, it's helpful, this is how I'm using the `MediaPicker`:

```
try
{
   var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
      {
         Title = "Pick Image"
      });

   if (result == null)
      return;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   // Log error
}
```

I never hit the `catch` block. It just crashes with the error message I mentioned above.

Any idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is definitely the AppIcon. Looks like .NET MAUI is not generating correct size icons from the `svg` that I had under `Resources\AppIcon`.

The workaround is to manually create the necessary icons -- in my case, I only created one 72x72 -- and placed them in `Platforms\Android\Resources\mipmap` folder. In my case, the `Resources` folder was there under `Platforms\Android` so I just had to create the `mipmap` folder.

I then had to go into `AndroidManifest.xml` file and correctly link them:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
```

So, in my case the file name for the app icon I manually generated is `ic_launcher.png`. I did have to have a second image named `ic_launcher_round.png`.

Looks like .NET MAUI is supposed to do this work but it's not doing it.

The second bonus -- which it shouldn't be -- is that when I now install the app on a device, I see the correct app icon for my app.

Here's a link to the issue I reported. Anyone experiencing this issue should up vote it so that it'll get the team's attention.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Changing-app-icon-of-NET-MAUI-app-then/10090581